# While running cron job getting the error Could not load the bundler gem. Install it with `gem install bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, ruby-on-rails-2

While running task from cronjobs getting the error

`preinitializer.rb:5 Could not load the bundler gem. Install it with gem install bundler`

But when I am running the same task from console, it is working fine.

`Bundler 1.13.6` is installed

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.8

Any suggestions on this

Comment: Maybe you are using different `rvm` gemsets

Comment: What is the line in your crontab?

Comment: More specifically, could your issue be solved by configuring it as something like: `/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /path/to/project && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e ....'`?

Comment: @TomLord - thanks for quick reply, my line of code is `*/1 * * * * JOBNAME="watch" TIMEOUT=30 $APP_DIR/script/cronhelper.sh $APP_DIR/script/runner -e production "Unit.watch"`

Comment: @Bustikiller - thanks for quick reply, I have only one version of ruby installed

Comment: Did you try running it as `/bin/bash -l -c '....'`? Any difference?

Comment: @TomLord - thanks It worked for me, I am still checking